# Properties of Direction Field of a Separable Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am investigating the general properties of the direction field of a separable differentiable equation. Is there some direct correlation between the equation being separable and the invariance in translation of the direction field? To illustrate, how can I figure out which $3$ of the direction fields below are that of separable differential equations?
[image]

Comment: Note that nullclines of separable equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f(x)}{g(y)}$  are only straight vertical or horizontal lines. Look at nullclines on these pictures, that will help.